# Paramaterized SQL Query C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

This is a simple query I have written. What would be the best way to paramaterize this to prevent SQL injection?

```
string selectQuery = "select [ID] from [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] where [myName] = '" +  user.globalUserName + "'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@` to define a parameter, like this:

```
string selectQuery = "select [ID] from [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] where [myName] = @username;";
```

Then you can define the parameter by using the `Command.Parameters` Function, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = user.globalusername;
```

or like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.globalusername);
```

Comment: Ben, with this i get "Must declare the scalar variable" for username. I am using the "or like  this" option